# Generating Java classes from XSD maven dependency in maven with JAXB (or others)

Tags: java, maven, xsd, jaxb

I have a data model stored in the Maven repo as an XSD file. My goal is to create a jar with all the Java classes representing this model. I want to use maven and JAXB to do this.
I know about the  maven-jaxb2-plugin (codehouse-mojo and java-net, not sure yet how they differ) but I don't see a way to use XSD from the maven dependency as an input. Do I have to write my own plugin to do this?

It doesn't have to be JAXB if there is a better tool to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** I'm the author of the [`maven-jaxb2-plugin`](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin).

Check the [documentation](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/wiki), it's right there. See [Specifying What To Compile - Specifying URLs, filesets and Maven artifact resources](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/wiki/Specifying-What-To-Compile#specifying-urls-filesets-and-maven-artifact-resources).

Example:

```
<configuration>                                                                                         
    <schemas>                                                                                       
        <!--
            Compiles a schema which resides
            in another Maven artifact.
        -->
        <schema>                                                                                
            <dependencyResource>                                                            
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>                               
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin-tests-po</artifactId>                    
                <!-- Can be defined in project dependencies or dependency management -->
                <version>${project.version}</version>                                   
                <resource>purchaseorder.xsd</resource>                                  
            </dependencyResource>                                                           
        </schema>                                                                                
    </schemas>                                                                                      
</configuration>
```

You can also use [catalogs](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/wiki/Using-Catalogs) to rewrite schema URLs to [Maven artifact resources](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/wiki/Referencing-Resources-in-Maven-Artifacts).

Example:

```
REWRITE_SYSTEM "http://schemas.opengis.net" "maven:org.jvnet.ogc:ogc-schemas:jar::!/ogc"
```

This will rewrite an URI `http://schemas.opengis.net/ows/2.0/owsAll.xsd` to `maven:org.jvnet.ogc:ogc-schemas:jar::!/ogc/ows/2.0/owsAll.xsd`. This will reference the `ogc/ows/2.0/owsAll.xsd` resource in `ogc-schemas` JAR artifact.

As far as I know, these features are unique to the [`maven-jaxb2-plugin`](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin).

Comment: Thank you lexicore. It works fine. I had to change the way I package my XSD file, as I just put it in the repo with a XSD packaging and I couldn't access the XSD file (unknown protocol: maven). Now I have a standard maven project with jar packaging and everything works as desired.